# How to add marker based folding to origami without affecting the default behavior

Tags: spacemacs

I am looking to activate vim style marker folding using origami without losing the default functionality. I know I can activate the marker options like so:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq-local origami-fold-style 'triple-braces)))
```

but then the default behavior is overwritten.

In case it matters: I am using `Spacemacs`.

Comment: What default behaviour?  Are you saying you don't want to lose emacs' default folding behaviour?  Are there particular aspects of that that you want to preserve?  I'm not personally a huge user of folding, except for org, but I suspect that what appears to you to just be "emacs default folding" may be the result of a lot of configuration in spacemacs, so it may pay to be more specific.

Comment: I just want to retain the default `origami` auto folding methods. For example, when coding in Common Lisp or Emacs Lisp it will fold `defun` etc. Quite standard stuff really. I don't think it is specific to Spacemacs.

Comment: Use file-local variables for files you want to use with marker based folding.

Comment: @nega I would like all files to be marker based while also retaining their usual folding behaviour. Is that possible with file-local variables?

Comment: That would be dependent on the folding package you used. The file-local variable would trigger the mode dependent setting.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't do what you want out of the box with `folding.el` `origami-mode` or `hide-show`. With `origami-mode` you get 1 parser per buffer, so you'd have to write you're own parser that understood the "default" folding and combined it with markers.

Comment: @nega yes that may, indeed, be the case. I might try to ask on the Origami Github page. All I need is a hook for additional rules. Maybe the functionality exist.